# How can I download all documents from Retrieve and Rank (Solr)?

Tags: solr, ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

We have a Cloudant database on Bluemix that contains a large number of documents that are answer units built by the Document Conversion service. These answer units are used to populate a Solr *Retrieve and Rank* collection for our application. The Cloudant database serves as our system of record for the answer units.

For reasons that are unimportant, our Cloudant database is no longer valid. What we need is a way to download everything from the Solr collection and re-create the Cloudant database.  Can anyone tell me a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any automated way to do this.

You'll need to fetch all your documents from Solr (and assuming you have a lot of them, do this in a paginated way - there are some examples of how to do this in the [Solr doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Pagination+of+Results)) and add them into Cloudant.

Note that you'll only be able to do this for the fields that you have set to be `stored` in your schema. If there are important fields that you need in Cloudant that you haven't got stored in Solr, then you might be stuck. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate one Cloudant database to another which will create you an exact replica.

Another technique is to use a tool such as [couchbackup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchbackup) which takes a copy of your database's documents (ignoring any deletions) and allows you to save the data in a text file. You can then use the *couchrestore* tool to upload the data file to a new database.

See [this blog](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/03/22/simple-couchdb-and-cloudant-backup/) for more details.